# React error: child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm a bit confused why the code below is generating the error: `child in a list should have a unique "key" prop`. In the component `SearchFilterCategory` I am adding add a key for each list item, which is a unique `id`. What am I doing wrong?

**SearchFilter.ts**

```
export interface SearchFilter {
    id: number,
    name: string
}
```

**SearchFilterMenu.tsx**

```
return (
    <>
        <ul className="list-unstyled">
            {searchFilterData?.map((data) => (
                <SearchFilterCategory filter={data} />
            ))}
        </ul>
    </>
)
```

**SearchFilterCategory.tsx**

```
export default function SearchFilterCategory(props: {filter: SearchFilter}) {
    return (
            <li key={props.filter.id}>
                {props.filter.name}
            </li>
    )
}
```

Comment: The key is in the wrong place. It needs to be on the component you're returning from the map.

Comment: `<SearchFilterCategory key={unique key} filter={data} />`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the key prop to the SearchFilterCategory component like this:

**SearchFilterMenu.tsx**

```
return (
    <>
        <ul className="list-unstyled">
            {searchFilterData?.map((data) => (
                <SearchFilterCategory key={data.id} filter={data} />
            ))}
        </ul>
    </>
)
```